# Android - Can't send image in base64 format to webservice over wifi

Tags: android, android-wifi

My scenario.
Android application that get pictures and other information and stores all in sqlite database.
WCF Webservice that receives the picture  in base64 format and the other data, all of them as string.
When sending with the image via HSDPA/3G it works perfectly, but if I turns wifi up and try to send, nothing happens, until get de timeout error.
When sending without the image, only other data, via HSDPA/3G it works perfectly, but if I turns wifi up and try to send, nothing happens, until get de timeout error.

Any ideias?

Thanks.

Edit:

Still can't send data over wifi.

I discovered that I can only send data that not exceeds 800bytes. I created two pictures with 800k and 900k, only the image with 800k was sent.
In 3G mode works perfectly.

What could be happening?

Comment: I suppose you've tried using a different WiFi network?

Comment: No. I dont have another wifi. The wifi works fine for other purposes, except when I try to send image to a webservice.